# Visual Studio restarts when having 2 elementHosts

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, elementhost

I have a usercontrol with 2 elementHosts whithin it.
I set the elementHosts' Child property programmatically in Load() event.
The problem is, when I try to add that user control to a form, Visual Studio restarts and I have no idea how to overcome this issue.

This problem holds for both VS 2008 and 2010.

Comment: VS is vulnerable to exceptions raised at design time.  You'll need to use the DesignMode property to avoid executing code in your event handlers that could raise such an exception.  If you have no clue what code might do this then start another instance of VS and attach it to the first one so you can make the debugger stop on the exception.

Comment: @HansPassant hey, thank you for your answer. I'm just considering how to use _DesignMode_ property. And I have no idea how to attach another instance of Visual Studio to my project. I would be thankful if you explain more.